# 411 response results in exception in Session.send

Tags: python, http, http-headers, python-requests, sigpipe

**UPDATE:** [The kind folks developing Requests.py are on the case.](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2490)

We're interacting (testing) with a HTTP service that responds with a 411 (Length Required) status code when no [Content-Length](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13) request header has been supplied in the presence of a request body;  This is to be expected as per [RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.4).

The problem we've encountered centres around the [Requests Python Module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#prepared-requests) (curl works as expected).  When sending an illformed request (lacking Content-Length in the presence of a request body) the service responds 411 and the connection is closed **by the remote** endpoint ([Connection: close](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13)).  This in turn throws an exception from the Requests Session.send method and we're unable to retrieve the HTTP response status code for validation.

*Is it possible to stop this situation (exception) and retrieve the HTTP response status code without altering the HTTP service?*

**Code**

```py
from requests import Request, Session

endpoint = "http://api.corvusoft.co.uk/resources"
request_body = '{ "data": {"core-temperature": "1,430", "core-temperature-units": "celsius", ... } }'

request = Request('POST', endpoint, data=request_body, headers={"Connection": "close"})
prepared_request = request.prepare()
del prepared_request.headers['Content-Length']

session = Session()
response = session.send(prepared_request)

print response.status_code
```

**Stack Trace**

```
Scenario: HTTP PUT without Content-Length                                                                                               
    Given I have initialised the core sensors
    And I perform a HTTP "POST" request to "/readings" with headers "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8, Accept: application/vnd.api+json":
      | """                                                   |
      | " { "data": {                                       " |
      | "     "id": "c0f22109-d258-4458-a3f5-0d16b2f55487", " |
      | "     "value": "acceptance-test"                    " |
      | "   }                                               " |
      | " }                                                 " |
      | """                                                   |
    When I perform a HTTP "PUT" request to "/queues/c0f22109-d258-4458-a3f5-0d16b2f55487" without header "Content-Length":
      | """                                                   |
      | " { "data": {                                       " |
      | "     "ttl": 30,                                    " |
      | "     "id": "c0f22109-d258-4458-a3f5-0d16b2f55487"  " |
      | "   }                                               " |
      | " }                                                 " |
      | """                                                   |
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/lettuce/core.py", line 144, in __call__
        ret = self.function(self.step, *args, **kw)
      File "/Users/Corvusoft/Development/test/acceptance/features/step_definitions/request.py", line 30, in i_perform_a_http_method_request_to_path_without_header_and_body
        i_perform_a_http_method_request_to_path_with_headers_and_body( step, method, path, "Accept: application/vnd.api+json, Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8", True )
      File "/Users/Corvusoft/Development/test/acceptance/features/step_definitions/request.py", line 91, in i_perform_a_http_method_request_to_path_with_headers_and_body
        response = session.send( request )
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send
        raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
    ConnectionError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

**Request**

```
POST /resources HTTP/1.1
Host: api.corvusoft.co.uk
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/vnd.api+json
Accept-Charset: utf-8

{ "data": {"core-temperature": "1,430", "core-temperature-units": "celsius", ... } }
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 304

{"errors":[{"status":"411","title":"Content Length Required", "description": "The server refuses to accept the request without a defined Content-Length. The client MAY repeat the request if it adds a valid Content-Length header field containing the length of the message-body in the request message."}]}
```

**Environment**

> Python: 2.7.5
>
> Requests: 2.5.3

Comment: Could you add the traceback you get for this error too?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Great idea :D, please hold...

Comment: If I substitute your endpoint for `http://httpbin.org/status/411` everything works just fine. That connection *is* closed (`Connection: close` is set on the response). As such I'm having a hard time reproducing your problem. Was that traceback still forthcoming? What version of `requests` are you using? (`import requests; print requests.__version__` will give you the current version).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Traceback is on the way.  I'm required to send it off to the client for sanitising before public display; don't ask!  Will post asap. thx

Comment: @MartijnPieters The Connection header from httpbin.org is keep-alive.  The remote endpoint (httpbin.org) is not closing the connection.  Therefore Requests is not displaying the same behaviour.

Comment: Ick, so it is; the example on http://httpbin.org/ implied it'd be closed. My mistake for not double-checking. You can still force it with a `Connection: close` request header, but `requests`/`urllib3` probably alters behaviour then.

Comment: @MartijnPieters adding Connection: close to the request will cause httpbin.org to respond with the correct header. I'll update my example to includes this header.

Comment: I see you are getting the `requests` / `urllib3` core devs on the case now; I see that the remote server closes the connection as soon as the request headers are sent without waiting for the body, probably a valid way to respond.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Correct. The Requests core team have taken up the case and hopefully will see a fix shortly.

Comment: If this is being discussed in Requests forum or such can you paste link here?

Comment: Please see my latest update.

Comment: Did this get solved ?

Comment: I've updated the question to fix the broken link (https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/2490);  no progress appears to have been made.